# python discard gibberish from unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm currently processing some strings in python, and I encountered some string that involves gibberish chars and some other languages.
For example,

```
u'أضعت طريقي! أضعت طري asd bla bla ���� bla bla □□□□ some more english and 123123 numbers'
```

What I want is to keep only real languanges (such as arabic, chinese, english and hebrew), numbers and other utf-8 characters (or preferably al32utf8).
So for the above example I would like to get  `u'أضعت طريقي! أضعت طري asd bla bla  bla bla  some more english and 123123 numbers'`.

I have already tried many combinations of python's encode, decode, unicode functions, in order to get rid of the gibberish, but have failed time after time.

I would really appreciate your help in the matter :)

Comment: Please show some of those "many combinations" you have tried, so we can help fix them.

Comment: How do you know which characters are "real languages"?  The squares and question mark symbols are generally due to the font not supporting the symbol or improper decoding of the data and could still be valid.  Python doesn't know if the font is displaying it incorrectly.  Real-world examples of the raw data (hex dumps) might help determine what the correct way of decoding could be.